# Run keyboard macro after open file?

Tags: init-file, terminal-emacs, keyboard-macros

Is it possible to run a keyboard macro in Emacs right after opening a file? For example, when I open a text file I want to get information in buffer `Hello world`.

Answer (score 1):

## Keyboard macro vs. Function

[Keyboard macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) are supposed to be fairly ephemeral things.
If you want something permanent, you should [write a Lisp function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/).

## Hooks

Emacs has a lot of ["hooks"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) - lists of functions run at certain point that you can customize for your needs.

"Opening a file" is done by [`find-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visiting.html) in Emacs.

Thus, <kbd>M-x apropos RET find hook RET</kbd> shows a list of hooks in the [`*Apropos*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Apropos.html) buffer, and you immediately see the one you need: `find-file-hook`.

So, all you need to do is (untested!)

```
(defun my-find-file-hook ()
  "Mention the newly visited file in the 'Hello World' buffer."
  (let ((fname buffer-file-name))
    (with-current-buffer "Hello World"
      (insert "just opened files " fname)
      (display-buffer (current-buffer)))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-find-file-hook)
```